# How can I improve my youtube search function?

Tags: php, sql, search, youtube

I'm trying to preform a simple youtube search based on data in a database. The data is being put into a table and I would like to have the song name be a link to a youtube search for that song. The idea is to add the artist name and song name to the end of the youtube search URL.

The problem is when the artists name or song name is longer than one word, the search only includes the first word. I'm using the following code right now:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <th>Song Name</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","checkout","Music Database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM MusicDB");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr><td><a href=https://www.youtube.com/results?hl=en&q=".$row['Song']."+".$row['Artist'].">".$row['Song']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Artist']."</td>"."</tr>";
  }


mysqli_close($con);

?>
</table>
```

For example, if the song is "Beat It" by "Michael Jackson", it will only add "beat" to the search.

If the song is "Thriller", it will add "Thriller+Michael".

If I add the song "Thrift Shop" by "Maclemore", it will add only "thrift" to the search.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `urlencode` to encode the values in your query string.

```
"<tr><td><a href=https://www.youtube.com/results?hl=en&q=". urlencode($row['Song'] . " " . $row['Artist']).">".$row['Song']."</a></td>";
```

You can also use `http_build_query`.

```
"<tr><td><a href=https://www.youtube.com/results?" . http_build_query(array(
  "hl" => "en",
  "q" => $row['Song'] . " " . $row['Artist']
)).">".$row['Song']."</a></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of either of these functions. I really appreciate your help.